# Accessing DIV of one iframe from another - jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe, html

I have an index page which has two iframes.

```
<iframe name="disp" id="dispframe" src="disp.php"></iframe>
<iframe name="type" id="msgframe" src="type.php"></iframe>
```

Now in type.php which is the bottom iframe, if I type some message and on submit, I want to change a particular div in the top iframe. (basically refresh contents from another file)

I could achieve a refresh by using: (and everytime during refresh, the new content for that div is fetched)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
parent.disp.location='disp.php'
</script>
```

But I want to change only a div in disp.php (say with id="loaddiv"). If I was to do it within disp.php itself, I would use something like this:

```
$('#loaddiv').load('newdisp.php');
```

Now I want to access loaddiv from the other iframe. I tried some things which didn't work.

```
$("#dispframe", parent).contents().find("#loaddiv").load("newdisp.php");
```

I know I'm wrong somewhere. Anybody can help with the right DOM traversal method?

Comment: This question already asked!Please verfy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: I want to access contents of one iframe from another iframe. Not just the contents of an iframe from the parent. How do I access the sibling iframe from this iframe?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fine.

```
var ele = window.top.IFRAME_NAME.$("#YOUR_ID");
```

//here you can do whatever with jquery
//example
ele.show();